# I’m trying to find the association between 2 variables by conducting a statistical test

Tags: anova, t-test, chi-squared-test, group-differences, methodology

My two variables are sex (male/female) and body mass index (BMI). I have a data set of 194 participants.

- Sex - 107 males (55.15%) / 87 females (44.85%)
- BMI - 23.88 +/- 5.03

I have no idea which test to run or how to run it. I'm leaning towards a $t$-test but I'm not really sure.

Please help!

Comment: what do you mean by find the association? correlation?

Comment: Do males or females have a high BMI?

Comment: Compute and compare the BMI's of the groups *separately.*  Plotting the two distributions is almost always informative and more useful than a mere test.

Comment: Is this a class assignment? I assume so. I assume they just want a t test of means.